# Bucle for each en vba en pagina web

Tags: excel, web, vba, foreach

Estoy haciendo webscraping y quiero saber cómo recorrer todos los elementos de una página web con un `for each` para encontrar un botón y darle click.

Lamento no poder adjuntar el código de la web ya que en mi trabajo tienen restringido todo debido a políticas de seguridad.

Pero la página es de un inicio de sesión donde metes usuario, contraseña y un botón de login.

Cabe mencionar que solo cuento con vba y todo lo hago en vba.

Soy novato en esto de programación.

Mi código es así.

```
Dim IE As Object 

Public Sub prueba 

Dim ruta As String 

Set IE = ICreateObject ("internetexplorer.application") 

Ruta = "paginaweb" 
IE.Navigate ruta

IE.Visible = True

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4 
Doevents
Loop

ie.getElementsByTagname("input") (1).value = "usuario"

ie.getElementsByTagname("input") (2).value = "contraseña"

ie.getElementsByTagname("button") (0).Click

Nota: quiero saber como hacer un ciclo for each en vba

End Sub
```